# How to bind Some Properties of MKMapView with some double variable in NSUserDefault?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

This is what apple said:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/cocoabindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002373-CJBEJBHH

Bindings in More Detail

**You can establish bindings easily in Interface Builder using the Bindings pane of the Info window.** In Interface Builder, the angle binding for a joystick that displays the offset and angle of graphics object’s shadow might look like Figure 6.
Figure 6  Bindings for a joystick’s angle in Interface Builder

Where is this so called Bindings Pane of the Info Windows. There is no such thing as info window. Is this still valid?